# How to synchronise child table data on hasMany relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have 2 table `products` and `variants`, with a *hasMany* relationship, the structure is below :

**Product Model** :

```
public function variants()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Variant::class);
}
```

**Variant Model** :

```
public function product()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

**Product Table** :

```
|     id          name            image          manufacturer
|     1           T-Shirt         t-s.jpg        docomo      
|     2           Short Skirt     s-skirt.jpg    docomo
```

**Variant Table** :

```
|     id     product_id      name       price    sku       quantity
|     1         1             S          30      ts-s       100
|     2         1             M          32      ts-m       100
|     3         1             XL         35      ts-xl      100
|     4         2             S          23      sk-s       100
|     5         2             M          25      sk-m       100
|     6         2             XL         28      sk-xl      100
```

I can save data on **Variant** model (child table) from **Product** model as :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{       
    $q = new Product;
    $q->name = $request->name;
    $q->save();
    // Below child table
    $q->variants()->createMany($request->variant);
}
```

I can store data, but the problem is that, how can I update child table? [**It can be create, update or delete**]
I tried with `sync()` method, but didn't work. Its for `manyToMany` relationship.

```
public function update(Request $request)
{       
    $q = Product::findOrFail($request->id);
    $q->name = $request->name;
    $q->save();
    // Below child table update
    // $q->variants()->sync($request->variant); // not worked
}
```

`sync()` works in `manyToMany` relationship. I need the same for `hasMany` relationship. 
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no `sync` method for `hasMany` relations. It's pretty simple to do it by yourself. You can simple delete the rows and insert them all again.

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{       
    $product->update(['name' => $request->name]);
    // Below child table update
    $product->variants()->delete();
    $product->variants()->sync($request->variant);
}
```

Comment: Don't do it this way because in the future you may need to store pivot data.

Comment: If he needs to save additional data in the pivot table he can simply pass an array in the sync method with the additional information. This is not a problem and would be a feature that you are not sure will be added.

Comment: The problem will be if we will have for example a `subvariants` table containing `variant_id` foreign key.   Regenerating `variants` records you break relations.